# Outlook becomes slow after using python win32com package to read emails

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

when I use win32com to access outlook  2013, my outlook is significantly slow after I run the code. below is my code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
emails = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['xyz'].Folders['abc'].Items
```

Sometimes I get com_error: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None) running the code if outlook is opened beforehand. I would have to restart outlook and reset my python env to be back to normal. Is there any setting in outlook that I need to set or any special python operation I need to do after reading the email?

Best regards,
Jeremy

Comment: Is there a reason you declare inbox on line 2 and then don't use it on line 5? My immediate thought is that your leaking objects...

Comment: Do you ever quit a win32com application? If it is still running along with other programs on a computer, it sucks the memory/other resourses and makes your original Outlook slow down.

Comment: @Evgeny - Outlook is a singleton, only one instance runs at any time. Check with the Task Manager

Comment: Is that your complete code? What do you do with the emails collection?

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever quit a win32com application? If it is still running along with other programs on a computer, it sucks the memory/other resources and makes your original Outlook slow down, that's my guess.

I do run a Word application like

```py
def win32_word_dispatch():
    # Lazy import of win32com - do not load Windows/MS Office libraries when
    # they are not called.
    import win32com.client as win32
    word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    word.Visible = 0
    return word
```

And try closing it as:

```py
def close_ms_word(app):
    app.Quit()
    # ISSUE: must also quit somewhere by calling app.Quit()
    # like in
    # http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23946-closing-excel-application
```

Comment: Outlook is a singleton, only one instance runs at any time. Check with the Task Manager